# How to cache files with Perl while playing sound files using vlc?

Tags: linux, perl, caching

I would like to manually cache files in  Perl, so when playing a sound there is little to no delay.

I wrote a program in Perl, which plays an audio file by doing a system call to VLC. When executing it, I noticed a delay before the audio started playing. The delay is usually between about 1.0 and 1.5 seconds. However, when I create a loop which does the same VLC call multiple times in a row, the delay is only about 0.2 - 0.3 seconds. I assume this is because the sound file was cached by Linux. I found [Cache::Cache](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cache::Cache) on CPAN, but I don't understand how it works. I'm interested in a solution without using a module. If that's not possible, I'd like to know how to use Cache::Cache properly.

(I know it's a bad idea to use a system call to VLC regarding execution speed)

```
use Time::HiRes;
use warnings;
use strict;

while (1) {
    my $start = Time::HiRes::time();
    system('vlc -Irc ./media/audio/noise.wav vlc://quit');
    my $end = Time::HiRes::time();
    my $duration = $end - $start;
    print "duration = $duration\n";
    <STDIN>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not as easy as just "caching" a file in perl. 
vlc or whatever program needs to interpret the content of the data (in your case the .wav file). 
Either you stick with calling an external program and just give it a file to execute or you need to implement the whole stack in perl (and probably [Perl XS Modules](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html)). By whole stack I mean: 
1. Keeping the Data (your .wav file) in Memory (inside the perl runtime). 
2. Interpreting the Data inside Perl.

The second part is where it gets tricky you would probably need to write a lot of code and/or use 3rd Party modules to get where you want.

So if you just want to make it work fast, stick with system calls. You could also look into [Nama](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Audio-Nama/README) which might give you what you need.

From your Question it looks like you are mostly into getting the runtime of a .wav file. If its just about getting information about the File and not about playing the sound then maybe  [Audio::Wav](https://metacpan.org/pod/Audio::Wav)  could be the module for you.

Answer (score 1):

Cacheing internal to Perl does not help you here.

1. Prime the Linux file cache by reading the file once, for example at program initialisation time. It might happen that at the time you want to play it, it has already been made stale and removed from the cache, so if you want to guarantee low access time, then put the files on a [RAM disk](http://enwp.org/tmpfs) instead.
2. Find and use a different media player with a lower footprint that does not load dozens of libraries in order to reduce start-up time. Try `paplay` from package `pulseaudio-utils`, or `gst123`, or `mpg123` with `mpg123-pulse`.